# mysql-workbench and Gnome keyring daemon problem

Tags: gnome, password, keyrings, mysql-workbench

when launching `mysql-workbench` I have the following warning:

```
[12:13:49] coil@coil:~$ sudo mysql-workbench &
[12:14:03] coil@coil:~$ ** Message: Gnome keyring daemon seems to not be available. Stored passwords will be lost once quit
[12:14:05] coil@coil:~$ Ready
```

Is there a way to fix this issue? Indeed, my passwords never get saved.

Comment: What Ubuntu version/release it this on? Cuz ... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61170

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll try all you suggested me soon. Thanks for the help. ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The bug has been fixed in MySQL Workbench 6.2.5 / 6.3.0 releases. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74771

A possible workaround was to add this code to the top of file `/usr/bin/mysql-workbench`

```
export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=1
```

This fix work on my ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL Workbench community 6.2.4 from `deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty workbench-6.2`

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue and providing the workaround - this is the cleanest approach!

Comment: Using  V6.3.6 error still persists

Answer (score 15):

There's a neat way I found, try this out.

Step 1: After installation unlock the workbench icon from launcher.

Step 2: press the super(window) button on your machine and search for workbench.

Step 3: Open workbench from the search results.

Step 4: Once open, lock the workbench icon to the launcher.

Voila !!! The keyring problem disappears.

---

Comment: Thanks.. Much Cleaner way to resolve this issue. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Works but an explanation would be nice...

Comment: Wow! I just realized that I always was launching workbench from dash (start menu) but not from launchbar. And now today after few years of using workbench launched it by clicking on launcher and got that problem!

Answer (score 9):

This answer is a variation on the guest1000's solution, but I don't have enough rep to create a comment.

Anyway, adding the following to ~/.bashrc also works and seems cleaner to me:

```
export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=$(ls -d /run/user/1000/keyring-*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this code to the top of file `/usr/bin/mysql-workbench`

```
if ls /run/user/`id -u`/keyring-* 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    gnome-keyring-daemon > /dev/null
fi

export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=$(ls -d /run/user/`id -u`/keyring-* | head -n 1)
```

It's not clean solution, but it works. No need of running workbench from terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I did as follows 
i am using Workbench 6.3

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/mysql-workbench
```

Just remove the comment

@line 5

```
WB_NO_GNOME_KEYRING=1
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
The simplest way I found is

1. Go to Ubuntu software center.
2. Search for MySQL workbench community.
3. Click on permission
4. Enable Read, add .... to on

Comment: Thanks worked for me

Comment: This is the most correct solution for snap users.

Answer (score 2):

mysql-workbench is looking for the `GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL` environment variable. If you are the only one using your computer, that variable should have a value similar to `/run/user/1000/keyring-XXXXXX`.

I had a similar problem with mysql-workbench package downloaded from dev.mysql.com (because MariaDB and Ubuntu's mysql-workbench package are incompatible) and a simple custom shortcut with the following launch command fixed the problem:

```
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=$(ls -d /run/user/1000/keyring-*) /usr/bin/mysql-workbench
```

Comment: no need to do as long as this. just type mysql-workbench from terminal

Answer (score 2):

The most stupid issue ever seen!

if you start your mysql-workbech by launcher this error comes out.

But if you start your mysql workbench from terminal keyring problem disappears.

Any ideas why this is happening? I was using version 6.0 and upgraded to 6.2.4 nothing changed. The workaround answer for this issue is Go terminal and start stupid workbench by Oracle...

Comment: I am having this issue and its 2017

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I just:

- Removed `mysql-workbench`.
- Downloaded `mysql-workbench deb package` from the official mysql page.
- Installed it with `dpkg` and it solved my problem.

I guess the problem was that I installed `mysql-workbech` with snap.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you had encountered the very same problem from 2014.

Comment: The snap works, the issue is with permissions. Have a look at Amrit's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238350/554832)